# How to make Tab bar transparent in native base android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

[image: Tab Bar View]

I want to make the tab bar transparent. I have tried changing its backgroundcolor to that of the screen put it still shows pushed out of the screen.

```
....

    *<Tabs
                tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                tabBarActiveTextColor={'white'}>
                <Tab heading="LOGIN">
                  <Tab1 {...props} />
                </Tab>
                <Tab heading="SIGNUP">
                  <Tab2 {...props} />
                </Tab>
              </Tabs>**
....
```